# Magento 2 : The proper way to read/save entities

Tags: magento2, database, model

I have been only for a few days in the Magento universe, starting with Magento 2, and I am currently a bit lost regarding the proper way to read and save entities (Model).

At the very begginning, I found a lot of tutorials where the author was using the *load()* and *save()* methods. After reading some documentation, I understood that it is because MG2 use an Active Record Pattern.

Coming from Symfony 2/3, I was a little bit disapointed at the beginning (used to Data Mapped Pattern with repository...). But not for long. But today, I found (thanks to the autocompletion of NetBeans) that the above method are deprecated (and so prone to disapear one day or the other...). After a quick search on Google, it seems that now MG2 is going to use more and more a repository pattern. OK that's cool.

But now, I was not able to found any proper tutorial to guide me to create a repository for a custom model. So I decided to look in the build-in module, opening some repos, and what did I found? Still those *load()* and *save()* methods.

I assume that's simply legacy code, but I am quite lost now. Does anyone know how to read and write custom entities in MG2?

Comment: You can look for inspiration in the catalog module to find repositories, but that can look scary at a first glance. Here is a [simple CRUD module](https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule) I've put together that uses repositories instead of save and load methods

Comment: Thank you Marius. It is, as you said, "scary", with so much things. But thanks to your work I understand the basics.